# How can I solve Java JLabel issues in application?

Tags: java, swing

I am quite new to Java. I decided to code tic-tac-toe as practice (from scratch).

Anyway, I am trying to have the 'JLabel label' change when I click; going from 1, then 2, etc. Eventually, it will change to something other than numbers. But, for now, it works for a test.

The 'System.out.println("Number of clicks: " + mouseIn);' works fine, and produces the output I want. A picture of the console and JFrame/JPanel/JLabel can be seen here:

[image]

(The little 1 in the JFrame is the JLabel. I want to match what is output in the console.

I have googled, and searched, and tried everything I know (which ain't much!) and I can't get the dang thing to work...I'm just asking for some guidance. Main method just includes building of JFrame/Panel.

Code below:

From the main class, called (namone.java [named it this for my own reasons]):

```
  public void run(JPanel p) //Takes panel from main method {
           
    for(int i = 0; i < ticList.length; i++){
        ticList[i] = new JButton(buttonText); //For every position in
        //ticList[], create a JButton object
       
        
        p.add(ticList[i]);
        ticList[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,140));
        
        ticList[i].addMouseListener(mouse); //Load mouseListner
        
    } 
    //Set mouseIn to click value in MouseEvents Class
    int mouseIn = mouse.getClicks();
    //Set text value to text value in MouseEvents class
    text = mouse.getText();
    
    //Output...
    
    System.out.println("Number of clicks: " + mouseIn); //For testing
    String mouse = Integer.toString(mouseIn); //Convert mouseIn value (from MouseEvents.java) to mouse
    JLabel label = new JLabel(); //New JLabel
    p.add(label); //Add label to screen
    label.setText(mouse); //Set the text of the label to value of mouse
    System.out.println(mouse); //For testing
    //So I can see if it's working (clicks wise)
    
    
   
    
}
```

And then the code from my MouseEvents.java class:

```
public class MouseEvents extends namone implements MouseListener {

int clicks = 1;
String text = "first"; //For testing purposes
public namone game = new namone();

public int getClicks(){
    return clicks;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public int intToString(){
    Integer.toString(clicks);
    return clicks;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    clicks++;
    intToString();     
    
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    
    text = "" + clicks;       
    game.run(p);
    
    
}
```

As I said. I am very new to Java and I'm trying to learn how to develop applications with it. I'm sure it's caused by my own ignorance.

Thanks.

Comment: *I can't get the dang thing to work* is not a great question. Try a debugger.

Comment: I am asking for some guidance.

Comment: In addition to learning to use a debugger, create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on a single button and label.

Comment: Try to repaint your panel after adding the label `panel.revalidate(); panel.repaint();`

Comment: @Khinsu - The OP's problem is that he never calls `setText` to update the text in the label. Nothing to do with repainting.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `mouse` is of type MouseEvents that you write, one possibility is that you need to pass `mouse.getText()` to your call to `label.setText(.)`.

Regardless, the way you set up your game is a bit strange to me. What is the reason to create a brand new `JPanel` every time someone clicks? Why not maintain the original JPanel and update it instead. I personally would attach a custom ActionListener to each JButton that runs some code everytime the button is clicked. If this ActionListener is an inner class, it can also view variables in the scope that the JButton is defined.